# meteor pass additional variable to template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template and I would like to pass an additional variable with it's data context:

```
<template name="list">
    {{#each item}}
        {{> listItem extraVariable=someValue}} 
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="listItem">
    {{extraVariable}}
</template>
```

I seem to lose the original datacontext (this from the each block) if I do it like in the above snippet. How can I keep the original and still pass the extra information (I do not want to use session variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor 1.2 and above:

```
{{#let x=y}}
```

> `let` block helper lets you set a new variable without overriding the data context inside the block

More info: https://quip.com/RXFlAk9Rc2xI

Comment: Thanks I now also found {{../variable}} in the docs which allows you to reference variables in the parent data context

Comment: Or pass context as a parameter, eg. `{{> listItem context=. extra=value}}`.